# Can I load jquery UI themes off the internet like google ajax libraries?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I know I can load the javascript ajax libraries from jquery and other sources from google, but is there a central place that you can reference for the standard themes in the jquery ui as shown on jqueryui.com, so I don't have to download a standard theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft's CDN has a nice group of jQuery UI themes: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNjQueryUI186.ashx

Answer (score 4):

Yes jQuery keeps a catalog of their stable themes, these can also be taken from the Google CDN.

Here are some links to some of their themes

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css

Note the formatting of thier formatting.  To see availble themes look on this page

http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: Grapped? Is this like Web 2.0 grep or something?

Comment: @Alex JL....lol...good catch...my english sucks I guess.  I speak bad english and bad(er) english.

Comment: Ha, no offense intended of course. I wish I spoke a 2nd language at ALL.